# Quickly fixing unmaintainable SCSS code in Rails

Tags: optimization, ruby-on-rails, sass

I've been working on a website and Rails and am fairly proud of my HTML semantics. However, my CSS code has become enormous in size, which is largely unnecessary for such a small website.

How could I shorten my code, make it easier to understand, and remove redundancy? I would prefer to have an automated process for this. If it helps at all, I do my editing in Vim, so I am happy with solutions that use that.

Here is my SCSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'baskerville_old_faceregular';
    src: url('baskvill-webfont.eot');
    src: url('baskvill-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('baskvill-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('baskvill-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('baskvill-webfont.svg#baskerville_old_faceregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'copperplate_gothic_boldRg';
    src: url('coprgtb-webfont.eot');
    src: url('coprgtb-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('coprgtb-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('coprgtb-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('coprgtb-webfont.svg#copperplate_gothic_boldRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'copperplate_gothic_lightRg';
    src: url('coprgtl-webfont.eot');
    src: url('coprgtl-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('coprgtl-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('coprgtl-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('coprgtl-webfont.svg#copperplate_gothic_lightRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    @media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
        .sign {
            position: absolute;
        }
        #post {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 3.55%;
            width: 1.5%;
            height: 960px;
        }
        #holder {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 2.2%;
            width: 44.3%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #board {
            position: absolute;
            left: 7%;
            top: 17.7%;
            width: 36.9%;
        }
        #logo {
            position: absolute;
            left: 9.25%;
            top: 24%;
            width: 30.55%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
        .sign {
            position: absolute;
        }
        #post {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 3.55%;
            width: 1.5%;
            height: 990px;
        }
        #holder {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 2.2%;
            width: 44.3%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #board {
            position: absolute;
            left: 7%;
            top: 10.7%;
            width: 36.9%;
        }
        #logo {
            position: absolute;
            left: 9.25%;
            top: 15.5%;
            width: 30.55%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        .sign {
            position: absolute;
        }
        #post {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 3.55%;
            width: 1.5%;
            height: 865px;
        }
        #holder {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 2.2%;
            width: 44.3%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #board {
            position: absolute;
            left: 7%;
            top: 9.2%;
            width: 36.9%;
        }
        #logo {
            position: absolute;
            left: 9.25%;
            top: 14%;
            width: 30.55%;
        }
    }

    .home {
        background: url(/assets/PaperBackground.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .find_me {
        background: url(/assets/Mill.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .wholesale {
        background: url(/assets/KraftPaper.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #topnav {
        list-style: none;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 4.5%;
        margin-top: 5.2%;
    }

    #topnav li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font-family: "copperplate_gothic_boldRg";
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #topnav li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }

    #topnav li a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #info {
        padding-right: 8%;
        padding-left: 650px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        float: right;
        width: 500px;
        font-family: "baskerville_old_faceregular";
        font-size: 23px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: center;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1365px) {
        #sidenav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 55%;
            list-style: none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        #sidenav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 42%;
            list-style: none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
        #sidenav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 67.5%;
            list-style: none;
        }
    }

    #sidenav {
        left: 7%;
    }

    #sidenav li {
        padding-bottom: 9%;
        font-family: "copperplate_gothic_boldRg";
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #sidenav li a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #sidenav li a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        #examples {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 7.5%; 
            margin-top: 10.5%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #examples img {
            width: 150px;
        }

        #examples td {
            padding-left: 70px;
            padding-right: 70px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
        #examples {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 7.5%; 
            margin-top: 10.5%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #examples img {
            width: 150px;
        }

        #examples td {
            padding-left: 25px;
            padding-right: 25px;
        }
    }

    #examples img {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px 0;
    }

    #examples p {
        font-family: "baskerville_old_faceregular";
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    #footer {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #footer #footer_links {
        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #footer #footer_links li {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "copperplate_gothic_boldRg";
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #footer #footer_links li a {
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #footer #footer_links li p {
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    #footer #footer_links li a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #footer #footer_links li img {
        width: 25px;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }

    #footer #footer-contact {
        font-family: "baskerville_old_faceregular";
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: 0;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .home #footer {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: -5px;
            height: 18px;
            clear: both;
            right: 200px;
            float: right;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
        .home #footer {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 20px;
            height: 18px;
            clear: both;
            right: 100px;
            float: right;
        }
    }

    .find_me #footer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 860px;
        right: 150px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .wholesale #footer {
            position: absolute;
            top: 860px;
            right: 300px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
        .wholesale #footer {
            position: absolute;
            top: 860px;
            right: 160px;
        }
    }

    #contact {
        position: absolute;
        right: 15%;
        top: 180px;
        width: 300px;
    font-family: "baskerville_old_faceregular";
    }

    #contact ol {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

  #contact ol li h3 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  #contact ol li h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  #contact ol li p {
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  #map {
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 500px;
  }

    #in_the_shop {
        position: absolute;
        left: 60%;
        top: 100px;
    }

    #shop_images {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5%;
        top: 450px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        #shop_images img {
            width: 170px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
        #shop_images img {
            width: 130px;
        }
    }

    #shop_images tr td {
        padding-left: 17px;
        padding-right: 17px;
    }

    #contact_header, #mobile_nav, #leaf_1, #leaf_2, #find_me, #mobile_find_me_footer, #mobile_map, #mobile_wholesale, #wholesale_mobile_catalog {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .sign {
        position: absolute;
    }
    #post {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 3.55%;
        width: 1.5%;
        height: 1000px;
    }
    #holder {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 2.2%;
        width: 44.3%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #board {
        position: absolute;
        left: 7%;
        top: 8%;
        width: 36.9%;
    }
    #logo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 9.25%;
        top: 11%;
        width: 30.55%;
    }

    #topnav {
        list-style: none;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 4.5%;
        margin-top: 5.2%;
    }

    #topnav li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
    }

    #sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10.37%;
        top: 30%;
        list-style: none;
    }

    #sidenav li {
        padding-bottom: 19%;
    }

    #examples {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 7.5%; 
        margin-top: 25%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #examples img {
        width: 150px;
    }

    #examples td {
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
    }

    #contact_header, #mobile_nav, #leaf_1, #leaf_2, #find_me, #mobile_find_me_footer, #mobile_map, #mobile_wholesale, #wholesale_mobile_catalog {
        display: none;
    }

    #info {
        padding-right: 5%;
        padding-left: 600px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        float: right;
        width: 400px;
    }

    #footer #footer_links {
        list-style: none;
    }

    #footer #footer_links li {
        display: inline-block
    }

    .home #footer {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 20px;
        height: 18px;
        clear: both;
        right: 130px;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything Sass specific here, is this just the compiled CSS?

Comment: It's SCSS, so it is handled slightly differently than normal CSS.

Comment: This is css? its not written in scss at all. scss would look like this for example:  `#footer #footer_links { list-style: none; li { display: inline-block;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/font_face/) for generating your font-face information.

Your media queries are a bit excessive here.  Other than your font-face block, there's not a spec of code that exists outside of a media query.

> The absence of support for media queries is in fact the ﬁrst media query.

Source: http://www.slideshare.net/bryanrieger/rethinking-the-mobile-web-by-yiibu

On top of that, you're failing to make use of cascade.  Compare:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1365px) {
    #sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        list-style: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 42%;
        list-style: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    #sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 67.5%;
        list-style: none;
    }
}
```

To:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        top: 42%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #sidenav {
        top: 55%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    #sidenav {
        top: 67.5%;
    }
}
```

Using values like 1024px and 1200px in your media queries indicates to me that you're designing for specific devices, rather than your content.  Consider the following code:

```
$breakpoint-medium: 45em;
$breakpoint-two-column: 60em;

header {
    // use the small logo
}
@media (min-width: $breakpoint-medium) {
    header {
        // use the bigger logo
    }
}

@media (min-width: $breakpoint-two-column) {
    // code to make a 2-column layout
}
```

There's quite a bit of code smell regarding your constant adjustments to things like positioning/margins, especially since you're using percentages (42% -> 55% -> 67.5%).  It smells like the fixed-width designs of yesteryear.  I can't comment any further here without seeing the impact it has on the layout.

You have quite a few overqualified selectors (eg. `#footer #footer_links li img` vs `#footer_links img`).  Always choose the shortest possible selector to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm relatively new to responsive design, so your suggestions are a great help.

Comment: This site has a great summary on various aspects of responsive design:  http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/

Answer (score 2):

You can DRY your use of **@font-face** using this mixin [see on codepen](http://codepen.io/Dygerydoo/pen/yebgPd) but you'll get better results using `compass`or `bourbon`, etc...

```
// Use variables instead names (name that vars as you wish, because I don't know which of them are the most used)
$primary-font: baskerville_old_faceregular;
$secondary-font: copperplate_gothic_boldRg;
$tertiary-font: copperplate_gothic_lightRg;

// -------------------------------------
//   Mixins
// -------------------------------------

@mixin font-face($font-name, $font-family-name) {
  font-family: $font-family-name;
  src: url('#{$font-name}-webfont.eot');
  src: url('#{$font-name}-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('#{$font-name}-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('#{$font-name}-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('#{$font-name}-webfont.svg##{$font-name}') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@include font-face(baskvill, $primary-font );
@include font-face(coprgtb, $secondary-font );
@include font-face(coprgtl, $tertiary-font );
```

Output result for first mixin:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: baskerville_old_faceregular;
  src: url("baskvill-webfont.eot");
  src: url("baskvill-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("baskvill-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("baskvill-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("baskvill-webfont.svg#sample-font") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

As @font-face you can mixin other things in your code like this:

```
.home {
    background: url(/assets/PaperBackground.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.find_me {
    background: url(/assets/Mill.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.wholesale {
    background: url(/assets/KraftPaper.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Turning it into this: (With the same output)

```
@mixin background-image($image-name, $image-file-format) {
  background: url(/assets/#{$image-name}.#{$image-file-format}) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.home {
  @include background-image(PaperBackground, png)
}

.find_me {
  @include background-image(Mill, png)
}

.wholesale {
  @include background-image(KraftPaper, png)
}
```

Other things you may want to change for best results.

**Use rem or em instead px**

Search info about this for some properties

**Use variables for colors**

Instead of repeating your primary color 9999999 times use something like this:

```
$black: black;
$navy-blue: #000080;
$mexican-red: #9b3d3d;

$primary-color: $navy-blue;
$secondary-color: $mexican-red;
```

Create some variables to identify primary, and secondary color (and if later you decide to change the primary color of whole website, it will be so easy as change navy-blue with the color you want)